# IOS MBProgressHUD display location error(it is not center,the loading display on left top.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, position, uiactivityindicatorview, mbprogresshud

I use `MBProgressHUD` showWhileExecuting to query some data from network,but the `MBProgressHUD` is not center sometimes

[image]

on pictures(red number):

loading displayed on left top and the backgound displayed at center.

1.loading display is not on background of MBProgressHUD
2.just show a background that doesn't contain loading

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //other code ...

    mb = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    // --> i try which causes also an error
    //[[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:self.view.window]; 
    // --> error too
    //[[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    mb.labelText = @"loding city...";

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:mb];
    [mb showWhileExecuting:@selector(queryCity:) 
                  onTarget:self 
                withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] 
             animated:YES];
}

-(void)queryCity:(NSNumber*)flag
{
    //query some data from network.
}
```

Comment: It is hard to see what the problem is with only the picture you provide and the short description.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Can you share how you solved it please? thanks

Comment: @user1349768 I still haven't solve the problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find this problem. 
when MBProgressHUD cleanup it will lost rect.

```
- (void)cleanUp {
taskInProgress = NO;
    //changed by zt9788 2012-12-26
    //comment this line to fix it.
//self.indicator = nil;
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
[targetForExecution release];
[objectForExecution release];
#else
targetForExecution = nil;
objectForExecution = nil;
#endif
[self hide:useAnimation];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

FYI: I fixed it by saying

`[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:_progress];`

instead of

`[self.view addSubview:_progress];`

I don't really like it, also because it works with `self.view` in another case, but I didn't see another option here.

Comment: Check out my code, its simple if your using the `MBProgressHud` and you don't have to access any `UIApplication` instances by yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Have a look at this, solved it for me and was very simple:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:_selfWeak.viewOverlay animated:YES].center 
 = self.viewOverlay.center;
```

If you save the instancetype you receive by calling `showHUDAddedTo:animated:` you should be able to do some more stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The MBProgressHUD automatically positions itself on the view that you add it to. Since you added it to the Navigation Controller View, it positioned itself to block any interaction with the Navigation Bar while in progress.

If that is not what you want to happen, then add the MBProgressHUD subview to a different view, in this case you probably want it on self.view rather than self.navigationcontroller.view.

Comment: i try to add MBProgressHUD to different view ,but it is display error sometimes also.

Comment: What is the error that it is displaying? Have you tried self.view instead of self.navigationcontroller.view?

Comment: loading displayed on left top and backgound displayed at center